# Why can the owner of a question downvote their accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, down-votes, accepted-answer

Sorry if that's a basic question, it just don't make sense to me.

Comment: Why would it need to be prevented?

Comment: Does "his accepted answer" refer to his own answer, or someone else's answer to his question?

Comment: I am having a hard time thinking of a use case where it's make sense.

Comment: But spending developer time on something like that (and thereby messing with how users can vote) doesn't make a whole lot of sense either.

Comment: @MarkAmery - I really liked your answer, can you post as one?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a plausible use case in which accepting and downvoting would at least not be utterly unreasonable: the answer is broadly correct and solves your problem, but is poorly written, hard to understand, and contains technical inaccuracies that you had to work around. You accept to show that the question has been answered, but vote down and tell the answerer what the problems are and say you'll vote up once they're fixed.

That said, I don't think it's allowed to deliberately enable the actions I've just described. It's probably allowed, as others have said, because nobody saw any point in banning it.

Comment: That makes sense.  In that case I would usually go ahead and just fix the answer instead of downvoting, because my acceptance "endorses" it to a degree.  (And because I may well need that info again in a year...)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Remember not everybody yet has edit powers. It's also possible that you have sufficient knowledge/expertise to recognize that the answer is defective, but not enough to be able to correct it adequately. But yeah, in general, I'd do the same as you.

Comment: Fair point.  (Everyone can *propose* an edit, right?  But yeah, knowing what's wrong and knowing how to fix it don't always go together.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Well, most everyone.  People that have been edit banned can't.

Answer (score 16):

Because every special case adds complexity, both in the code and in the UI.  Some pathologies just aren't worth preventing.

(For example, if you do this, then you need to provide a UI hint when he attempts to downvote the answer he accepted, and/or deal with the question on meta, probably more than once.)

Comment: _"Some pathologies"_! Brilliant! I wish the data explorer had who downvoted so I could go and find the list of diseased people for you.

Comment: I meant that the case of both accepting an answer and wanting to downvote it sounds pathological.

Comment: I realised; I bet there's hundreds out there :-).

Comment: I was disappointed to see this answer not having been accepted and downvoted.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure there are lots of things I can do on this site that make no sense.

- I can downvote an answer I accept on a question: "This is the best answer, but it's not useful."
- I can randomly upvote or downvote, without knowing the subject matter, or without even reading the question.  I can add random noise to the reputation system.
- I can award a bounty on a question, independent of any merit the question might have.
- I can delete a whole bunch of my good answers.  I might trigger an answer ban.  Just because I like pain.

You can do these things, but why?  Furthermore, why should we stop you?  Doing any, or all, of these things won't change the direction of the earth's rotation.  It won't even affect this site very much.

Comment: The deleted answers are likely to be undeleted (you don't own them so if anybody thinks they're valuable they'll come back), but yeah.  You can do all sorts of things that don't make sense; we can't prevent all of them nor should we.